# setContentView and turn decive

Tags: android, setcontentview

I have two screens and two xml-files for one activity. In my `onCreate` method I call the fist one and handle some user input. After that I am changing my layout with

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz2);
```

and everything is fine and works as intended but when I run the application and turn my device **after** I switched the layouts. It will just switch back to the first layout and stay on that layout (every button and all works as well).

How can I prevent my screen from changing back my layouts when I turn my device?

Comment: When you rotate a device, the entire activity is rebuilt from scratch, meaning any changes you've made are discarded and onCreate is run again. If you want to keep changes, you've got to look at onSaveInstanceState and using a Bundle to register where you were in the app.

Comment: yeah you have to save your state to the bundle. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Comment: you need to handle one flag if you are changing layout then store flag value in sharedpreference and then check for that flag from sharedpreference if its true than set second xml as your layout or else set first as you content of activiy.

Answer (score 0):

It's switching back to the first layout because when you rotate the screen the whole `Activity` is recreated. You have couple of options to deal with this:

1. Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your `<activity` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This way you're telling the system you want to deal with the rotation yourself (and if needed you can perform some actions in `onConfigurationChanged()` method).
2. Use `Fragments` to display the two "states" you have (I'm assuming those are `quiz1` and `quiz2`). This way you won't need to do multiple `setContentView()` in your activity.

The second option is the one to go for, as that's basically what `Fragments` are all about. Not to mention you can do very nice transitions between them (fade-in-out animations, etc) and your UX will be much better than when swapping the `setContentView()`.